# Avoid showing my URL in a webview Android application

Tags: android, networking, android-webview

I need an effective way to not show the URL of my page for example when I disable my network connections and I click on any 'link' in my application. 
I'm already doing a check before starting the application, and also when I click a button action bar that redirects me to my home page, but when for example I am browsing at my application inside the webview, and I disable my wifi and 3G connections, and I click on something, the webview returns me an error connection: "Web page not available", and also shows my URL. I can not let that happen in my application, anyone knows how to check the connection in which 'page load' that the application do?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom html and put it in asset folder. And

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Logger.d("url", url);
            //              if(url.contains(".") && !url.startsWith("http://docs.google.com") && !url.startsWith("https://docs.google.com") && docSupported.contains(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase())){
            //                  openURL(url);
            //              }else
            //              super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(mWebView, url);
            if(Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity().getApplicationContext()))
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            else
                mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage.html");
            selectedImageFile = null;
            return true;
        }}
```

That is it.

You can also do this in **onError** method of **WebChromeClient** but it is not working in some OS versons.

Comment: Thankyou friend, i'll try this now. Could you please answer me a newbie's question ? android_asset folder I have to create and put into my android project or can i use the 'asset' folder already existent?

Comment: If not exists you can create it under your application folder name **assets**

Comment: Friend, I did what you said, but the webview still showing the same error, only now instead of revealing my 'URL', it shows the "file :/ / / error / errorpage.html". 
What can I have done wrong? 
I used the 'assets' folder that already had in my project, and I created inside another folder called 'error'. The 'file link' is like that right?

Comment: Sorry friend, I have realized where I was going wrong! I did not know that I should use exactly 'android_asset /' in the path. 
Now I did it! 
Thank you! You saved my life hahaha

Comment: @UiuSilveira You welcome. If it helps you then please select my answer. Thanks.